# sharepoint rest api max query length

Tags: rest, querystringparameter

We are trying to post a really long query string, that exceeds 2048 characters to sharepoint rest api.I am making a post to the below api

http://sitename/_api/web/sitegroups?$select=LoginName,Id,Title&$Filter=LoginName%20eq%20'Test_Grp'

We modified the config file of our sharepoint site to the below,

```
    <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="65536"/>

 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxQueryString="65536" />
```

But still sharepoint throws a 400 error stating that the maxquery length is exceeded. Do I have to change the configurations in some other place?

Is it possible to send the query string as part of the http post body so that the query string length could be let alone ?

Answer (score 0):

> SharePoint REST supports maximum query length of 256 characters
>   excluding query options.

Looking at your REST query, there is not issue. Please send the error message you are getting to resolve your query.